# have you ever had this error?-numbers of left and right parentheses in Newick string not equal- tree in R

Tags: r, tree

The above error is occurring when trying to read a tree .
`tree <- read.tree(paste0(table_dir,'tree.19.08.tre'))`
I tried to reproduce the error but with other trees, for example with the `iris` example dataset it worked perfectly. The tree was generated with  `write.tree(tree, file='C:/Users/J/Desktop/proj/d/t/tree.19.08.tre',append = FALSE)`. I can look at `tree` in the programme FigTree (javascript based). Maybe it looks a bit strange but why can´t I open it in R?
Any suggestions?

That is a cutout of `tree` in figtree, in case it helps ;)

[image]

That is the full error:

```
Fehler in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : numbers of left and right parentheses in Newick string not equal
3.
FUN(X[[i]], ...)
2.
lapply(STRING, .treeBuild)
1.
read.tree(paste0(table_dir, "tree.19.08.tre"))
```

Comment: we really need a [mcve] to figure out what's going on here ...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I couldn't load it with `DECIPHER` either, but I made it with `phytools`:

```
library(phytools)
tree = read.newick(treeFileName)
```

Exploring the loaded `phylo` object I realized that the tree was not correct, the reason being that the leaves of the tree contained in the name semicolons, as it is costumary in some taxonomic formats, e.g.

> d__Bacteria;p__Proteobacteria;c__Gammaproteobacteria

and the problem is that the semicolon indicates the end of the tree in [newick format](https://evolution.genetics.washington.edu/phylip/newicktree.html). Simply transforming the semicolons into other symbol, e.g.

> d__Bacteria|p__Proteobacteria|c__Gammaproteobacteria

solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've got exactly the same error when loading a tree I got from a colleague.
But I was able to load it using
`tree <- DECIPHER::ReadDendrogram(treeFileName)`

Comment: In general I think it is helpful to add a link to the package, this one in particular is available via BioConductor: [DECIPHER](http://www2.decipher.codes/)