# can´t read in tree in r

Tags: r, tree

I already posted this question, but did not get any answers [numbers of left and right parentheses in Newick string not equal- tree in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63490984/numbers-of-left-and-right-parentheses-in-newick-string-not-equal-tree-in-r). I do not know how to solve it. I have a tree written in .tre format and also .txt format. Whenever I try to read it in R with read.tree it shows me

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : numbers of left and right parentheses in Newick string not equal
3.
FUN(X[[i]], ...)
2.
lapply(STRING, .treeBuild)
1.
read.tree(paste0(table_dir, "tree.keto.19.08.tre"))
```

I can´t reproduce the error. I can open tree in the java programme figtree, that is possible.

```
write.tree(tree, file='C:/Users/J/Desktop/p/d/t/tree.19.08.tre',append = FALSE)##write
tree <- read.tree(paste0(table_dir,'tree.19.08.tre'))##read
```

The directory is right.
Any suggestions what is wrong?

Comment: To get answer you need to follow the guidelines at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.  In particular a self contained minimal reproducible example that anyone can copy and paste from the question into R to see the error.

Comment: Thank you @G.Grothendiek  actually I know that. But I can´t reproduce the error in a reprex or the ```iris``` dataset...